# Dynamic text colour in ArcGIS Pro Table Frame

Tags: arcgis-pro, attribute-table, element, dynamic-tables, table-frame

Has anyone figured out a way to alter the text properties (colour, boldness, font, etc.) of a table element based on a specific property in ArcGIS Pro?

For example, I want to add tables to a layout in Pro and have certain cell text highlighted if they are above or below a certain value or colour a specific way if the value in the cell exceeds a threshold.

I'm using the most recent version of ArcGIS Pro where table elements have been added and can be dynamically linked to the extent of the map.

Comment: If ArcGIS Pro Table Frames cannot do this then I am confident that an approach I teach in [Challenging times with Python and ArcPy for ArcGIS Pro](https://www.udemy.com/course/challenging-times-with-python-and-arcpy-for-arcgis-pro/?referralCode=93AF10701559771AA2C3), that uses table-like feature classes in their own map frame, could be used.